# AngularJS Web Application - Performance Issue (Chrome / Firefox)

Tags: angularjs, performance, google-chrome, user-interface, firefox

**High level Architecture**

AngularJS -> REST API -> Middleware -> MySQL DB

**Deployment Setup**

NGINX -> Tomcat -> Middleware (3rd Party BPM solution) -> MySQL DB
NGINX Reverse Proxy to Tomcat -> Tomcat (Web Service Layer) -> BPM (Middleware)

Response time for XHR based requests across different browsers in the same system (Windows 10 Pro 64 bit OS) varies
Chrome - 8-12 seconds
Firefox - 1-4 seconds

Refer the screenshot for the time taken in both the browsers

[image]

Refer the Chrome browser Headers for one of the requests

[image]

**Observation so far**

1) Server processing time for any XHR request across NGINX, Tomcat and Middleware are in milliseconds based on the server logs. There is no variation when it's being accessed from Chrome or through Firefox.

2) Network related problem is ruled out as other Internet and Intranet applications are working as expected

Need help in improving the performance..

Comment: Is it AngularJS(1.6.*) or is it Angular(>2)? Because AngularJS has nothing to to with the response time from your server. 
Also maybe your SQL Statement is very slow.

Comment: AngularJS  version is 1.4.7. I have checked the SQL statement execution. there is no variation and clue